# Error while installing Bugzilla

Tags: apache2, bugzilla

I am trying to install Bugzilla on centos. Everything in the terminal went fine. But when I try to access Bugzilla through my browser, it is returning the error as shown below.

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it.
The document tree is shown below.
<D:error><C:error/><m:human-readable errcode="2">
Could not open the requested SVN filesystem
</m:human-readable></D:error>"
```

Can any one help me to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above error rises when there is port conflict between SVN and other applications.
We need to configure virtual host inorde3r to avoid port conflict between svn and other applications.